# store selected grid view value into database

Tags: asp.net

I've a gridview in which a radiobutton is used to select a particular row of data. Now I need to save  radio button selected row into database. How do I achieve this?  I'm not using JQuery or Ajax, my entire coding is done on ASP.NET

Comment: post your works you have done until now

Comment: @Yamini you should use chekbox in place of radio button and u can do this work either on click of button or any event of gridview..

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I didn't got your problem correctly,But the ideal methodology is to use **Check box** instead of **Radio button** will be far better for your coding purpose.

The below code is a demo for inserting the values into the database from a grid view where in the particular rows will be inserted which has been checked.

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionstring"].ToString());

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string active = "N";
    for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        string A = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
         string B = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
        CheckBox Ckbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (Ckbox.Checked == true)
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into table_name(A,B) values (@A,@B)";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = cn;

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A", A);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@B", B);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();



    }


}
```

Hope this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Easy

1. Search through GridRows
2. FindControl radio button on each row.
3. Check that button is Checked or not.

and now try it.